# proof that$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ e (2-1)^n}{n!} $

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I wanted to use series expansion of exp function.
I have a doubt about what i found.

Knowing exp series has a radius of convergence infinite, we have that expansion serie center at 0 is 
$exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $

So choosing x=2 it gives :
$exp(2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!} $

Now i use maclaurin formula to determine exp exapnsion at c= 1. I obtained $ exp(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ e (x-1)^n}{n!} $
So choosing x=2 it gives :
$ exp(2) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ e (2-1)^n}{n!} $

Finally, it means that

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ e}{n!} $

Comment: You probably mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\dotsb)$, your expression makes no sense.

Comment: yes i made mistake i edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that

- $\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}  = e^2$

and

- $\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ e}{n!} =e\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} =e^2$

Comment: Yes it is thank, but i think it s counterintuitive but it seems to be true

Comment: It’s a direct consequence of $$exp(x)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $$ for $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to prove the more general result that $\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{l\ge 0}\frac{y^l}{l!}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}$. What is the $x^k y^l$ coefficient? On the left, $\frac{1}{k!l!}$; on the right, $\sum_{n=k+l}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n!}=\frac{\binom{k+l}{k}}{(k+l)!}=\frac{1}{k!l!}$.